# Mongoose update the field of the nested document not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've tried to update the field of the nested sub document using mongoose.
Here are the model and source code.
Model

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var info_schema = mongoose.schema({
   info:Schema.Types.Mixed,
},{collection:'info'});
var InfoModel = mongoose.model('info', info_schema);
```

I've tried to execute `db.info.updateMany({'info.addition.group':myid},{$set:{'info.addition.field1':'a','info.addition.field2':'b'}})` in mongoshell.
It worked well,but it didn't work using mongoose.

```
 InfoModel.updateMany({'info.addition.group':myid},{$set:{'info.addition.field1':'a','info.addition.field2':'b'}}).exec();
```

Why doesn't mongoose update the field of the sub nested document?
So I tried to described the model in more detail.

```
 var info_schema = mongoose.schema({
   info:{
      addition:Schema.Types.Mixed,
      otherinfo:String,
      modified:Number,
      ....
    },
 },{collection:'info'});
```

At this time , mongoose threw out the error.

> CastError: Cast to number failed for value "a" at path "addition"

What did I do incorrectly?
What is the reason of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works using your code and modifying it a little bit:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var info_schema = new Schema({  // <-- just use Schema
   info: Schema.Types.Mixed
},{collection:'info'});
var InfoModel = mongoose.model('info', info_schema);

InfoModel.updateMany({'info.addition.group': 1},  // <-- I used 1 for testing
{ $set: { 'info.addition.field1' : 'a', 'info.addition.field2' : 'b' } }).exec()
```

Tested locally after first creating a record with `info.addition.id` == 1 so that I can update it etc.

Comment: So maybe the problem was just a typo in `mongoose.schema` instead of using `mongoose.Schema` or the previous declared variable `var Schema = mongoose.Schema`

Comment: Not 100% I wanted to let the OP know that this works so it could be as simple as a typo. I could not even run with `mongoose.schema({` so I would think OP would have pointed that out.

Comment: Well first lets confirm that it is the `new Schema` or just `Schema` because it should work both ways ... what would not work is using `mongoose.schema` since that is not a thing.